# Dynamic/Generic XSLT for Verical and Horizontal Layouts

Tags: xslt

I have the following XSLT. It works **great** for horizontal layouts. However when there are too many columns I need it to flip to a vertical layout. Ultimately being able to configure or specify the number of columns in a variable would be best. Can anyone kindly help?

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1]/*" mode="th"/>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/*/*/*" mode="th">
    <th>
      <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    </th>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/*/*">
    <tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/*/*/*">
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That XSLT generates a single HTML table. It is not clear which result you want instead, generating more than one table if there are more columns than you want to put in a single table?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I have understood the question correctly but if you just want to output several tables, each having `$cols-per-table` columns, then I think the adaption of the presented code to

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:param name="cols-per-table" select="10"/>

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" doctype-system="about:legacy-doctype"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*[1]/*[position() mod $cols-per-table = 1]" mode="page"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="page">
      <xsl:param name="page-no" select="position()"/>
      <table border="1">
          <thead>
              <xsl:apply-templates select=". | following-sibling::*[position() &lt; $cols-per-table]" mode="th"/>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/*">
                  <xsl:with-param name="page-no" select="$page-no"/>
              </xsl:apply-templates>
          </tbody>
      </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*/*/*" mode="th">
    <th>
      <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    </th>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*/*">
    <xsl:param name="page-no"/>
    <xsl:variable name="first-col" select="1 + $cols-per-table * ($page-no - 1)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="last-col" select="$first-col + $cols-per-table - 1"/>
    <tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[position() >= $first-col and position() &lt;= $last-col]"/>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*/*/*">
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyRYYjr/1

I have used XSLT 1.0 as the original code used that version although with XSLT 2/3 and positional grouping using `for-each-group` and/or a key computing the "pag" a "column" element belongs to might be more efficient:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="cols-per-table" as="xs:integer" select="10"/>

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

  <xsl:key name="page-no" match="/*/*/*">
      <xsl:variable name="index" as="xs:integer">
          <xsl:number/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:sequence select="($index - 1) idiv $cols-per-table + 1"/>
  </xsl:key>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*/*[1]/*" group-adjacent="(position() - 1) idiv $cols-per-table">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="page">
              <xsl:with-param name="page-no" select="position()" tunnel="yes"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="page">
      <xsl:param name="page-no" tunnel="yes"/>
      <table border="1">
          <thead>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" mode="th"/>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/*"/>
          </tbody>
      </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*/*/*" mode="th">
    <th>
      <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    </th>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*/*">
    <xsl:param name="page-no" tunnel="yes"/>
    <tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('page-no', $page-no, .)"/>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*/*/*">
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyRYYjr/4

At https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyRYYjr/5 I have implemented a pure XSLT 3 approach solely using `for-each-group` and storing the "pages" and "columns" in a `map`.